# Posting data from winforms to mvc controller passes null value

Tags: winforms, http-post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to post a string value from winforms (which is a ClickOnce application) to MVC controller action method. Am able to successfully call the POST method, but on checking the parameter value it shows as null value.

Following is my winform code:

```
private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtFill.Text);
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://abc.azurewebsites.net/Home/Contact");            
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        Stream dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

        dataStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        dataStream.Flush();
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        lblShow.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.  
        lblShow.Text += " " + responseFromServer;

        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();                                  
    }
```

Following is the screenshot from my controller action method where the breakpoint gets hit, but parameter post value is null.

[image]

Any approach / suggestions on what is going wrong or how to pass a string or JSON values from winforms to my mcv controller action.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data="+txtFill.Text);
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://abc.azurewebsites.net/Home/Contact");            
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        Stream dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

        dataStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        dataStream.Flush();
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        lblShow.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.  
        lblShow.Text += " " + responseFromServer;

        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();                                  
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Once I hit the ActionMethod, it does not show the View of that action method in the browser. Any way to redirect user to the browser link using the above logic?.